# Cannot invoke primitive type int

Tags: java, arrays

Its coming up with "Cannot invoke getNumber() on the primitive type int. Why?

public Card findLargest() {

```
    ArrayList<Card> cardStack;}
    public Card getLargest() {
      Card largest;
      Card c;
      for (int i = 1, largest = cardStack.get(0); i < cardStack.size(); i++) {
        c = cardStack.get(i);
        if (largest.getNumber() > c.getNumber()) {
          largest = c;
          continue;
        } else if (largest.getNumber() == c.getNumber()) {
          if(largest.getSuit().equals("Diamonds"))
              largest = c;
            continue;
```

Comment: Well I really don't have any idea what to do, so Ive just tried stuff like Card, c.getNumber(), largestNumber,etc. I really dont know what to do

Comment: Ffs why can someone not just help me haha

Comment: @MarkFoley Because this site isn't for helping you with homework?

Comment: @MarkFoley Because this is not a rent-a-coder type of website. You have to ask a specific question on a specific problem you have. Not ask us to complete your own task. I strongly suggest you start reading some introduction to Java first, then try to complete your assignment.

Comment: Not enough time to read an introduction to java, got this assignment at the last minute and have other classes that are more important!

Comment: Then come back to it when you have more time; nothing will be accomplished through typing in random stuff, or parroting back what someone thinks the answer is.

Answer (score 1):

```
largest = c;
```

Since you need to have your `largest` variable now reference the card with the new highest value you simply want to point the variable to it.

Next time around `largest.getNumber()` will return what `c.getNumber()` is returning now.

Make sure the declaration for `Card largest;` is outside of your loop however.

EDIT:

I'll add some explanation for you and hopefully answer your questions.

When you declare an Object as such:

```
Card c;
```

You're creating a reference variable that can refer to any object (or subclass) of the Card type. By creating an instance of that object...

```
Card c = new Card();
```

you are reserving memory and initializing its children objects/primatives.

So when you write a function like this:

```
List<Card> cardStack; //Just assuming you have a List of cards
public Card getLargest() {
  Card largest;
  Card c;
  for (int i = 1, largest = cardStack.get(0); i < cardStack.size(); i++) {
    c = cardStack.get(i);
    if (largest.getNumber() > c.getNumber()) {
      largest = c;
    } else if (largest.getNumber() == c.getNumber()) {
      if(...)//Check suits as you would
    }
  }
  return largest;
}
```

You are creating variables that refer to the Card objects that exist in the stack. There are no new memory allocations happening for the references (besides the memory they need to hold the reference).

As a result, you'd have a list of card objects that you created elsewhere, and two references, `c` and `largest` that simply point to the objects stored in a different location. Returning `Card` from the function returns that reference so any actions you do on it effect the card it refers to.

Alternatively you'd `clone` the object and send back an identical, but distinct object where any modifications you do to it are not affecting the original Card. In many objects, the ability to only create new ones, never modifying an old one, is called Immutable. String objects are immutable objects for instance.

When I talk about needing to have `Card largest;` written outside the loop it means that the memory allocated to holding the reference only exists in the scope of the loop. If we were to do this:

```
for (....) {
  Card largest;
  //...
}
```

...each time the loop iterates the `largest` variable is destroyed and recreated, removing and references or data we held in it. For my larger example above, we could put `Card c;` in the loop because we only care about what `c` is for the duration of the loop while largest matters later on. This is called Variable Scope.

Comment: Not even sure what you mean :P I'm hopeless at this

Comment: I've put up some more details for you. I hope it makes sense.